# JavaScript код не выводит результат с первой попытки

Tags: javascript

Когда я запускаю скрипт (см. ниже) с первой попытки не удается получить результат,

переменная "result" выводит "underfined"

```
var result;
Promise.resolve('information')
    .then(res => {return result=res})
    result;
```

**Попытка №1**

[image: Посмотреть результат №1]

**Со второй попытки уже присваивается значения**

[image: Посмотреть результат №2]

**Вопрос:** Как ожидать присвоения значения переменной "result", без использования setTimout-ов. Сгодится цикл while или MutationObserver, но у меня не получается. Можете подсказать где у меня ошибка?

**Важное условия "console.log" использовать нельзя!**

**Ожидание с помощью цикла While**

```
var result;
var finito = false;
Promise.resolve('information')
    .then(res => {return result=res})

while(finito != true)
{
  if (result != undefined)
  {
    result;
    finito=true;
  }
}
```

---

Дополнение:

```
let promise = Promise.resolve('information');
promise.then(handler);
function handler(data) {
  return data;
}
```

[image: Посмотреть результат №3]

Answer (score 1):

```js
let promise = Promise.resolve('information');

promise.then(handler);

function handler(data) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: прошу прощения, забыл указать что необходимо без использования console.log, пример как у меня на скрипте

Comment: А какая разница. Консоль я указал только для того, чтобы показать, что прилетает "приготовленная" переменная. В функции может быть любая обработка данных

Comment: покажите пожалуйста пример без console.log-а очень вас прошу, уже вторую неделю голову ломаю никак не получается

Comment: Вместо вывода в консоль напишите **ЛЮБОЙ** код, который работает с результатом.

Comment: Вверху, я добавил дополнение, пожалуйста посмотрите результаты

Comment: Зачем return в handler, если там должна быть обработка результата, который возвращает promise?

Comment: то как я записал, это потому что мне нужно что то подобное этому, это для отправки скрипта в cefSharp, cefSharp не принимает console.log, поэтому мне нужно что то подобное, как я показал в своих примерах. **Главное - вывести информацию так как я показал в последнем скриншоте**

Comment: "Главное - вывести информацию так как я показал в последнем скриншоте" --- ровно это и происходит в коде в ответе

Comment: А что надо использовать? Тебе вывести надо. Информация выводится. Что не так? Сформулируй нормально что ты хочешь.

Comment: Уважаемый, я этот скрипт вставлю в cefSharp, cefSharp не выводит данные которые записаны в console.log, поэтому мне нужно вывести так как я писал в своих примерах или на подобие этого лишь бы не использовать console.log и setTimeout. Лучше всего методом return переменная или просто указав саму переменную как у меня в примерах

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в том, что не понимаешь как устроен Event Loop и соответственно - как работает JS Runtime.

Код

```js
var result;
Promise.resolve('information')
        .then(res => {return result=res})
        result;
```

обработается вовсе не последовательно. Сначала выполнятся строки 1, 2 и 4 и только после этого - строка 3.

Comment: А как сделать чтобы выполнился 1,2,3,4?

Comment: Обработчик Promise `.then(res => {return result=res})` запустится ПОСЛЕ окончания работы скрипта. Именно поэтому у тебя не получится вывести содержимое переменной `result` со значением 'information': на момент окончания работы скрипта переменная не проинициализирована (равна undefined)